# Default value for props like an object didn't work

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a very strange situation :

My `HomeComponent.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png" />
    <HelloWorld :msg="msg" @update="inputUpdated" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent } from "vue";
  import HelloWorld from "@/components/HelloWorld.vue"; // @ is an alias to /src
  import { Message } from "@/interfaces/message";

  export default defineComponent({
    name: "Home",
    components: {
      HelloWorld,
    },
    setup(props, { emit }) {
      const msg: Message = {
        year: 2020,
      };
      function inputUpdated(value): void {
        console.log("Get Event : " + value);
      }
      return {
        msg,
        inputUpdated,
      };
    },
  });
</script>
```

My `HelloWorld.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg.title }} in the year : {{ msg.year }}</h1>
    <button @click="increment">count is : {{ count }}</button>
    <div>{{ pow(2, 3) }}</div>
    <p>Edit <code>component</code> to test state is {{ state.year }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent, ref, reactive, PropType } from "vue";
  import { State } from "@/interfaces/state";
  import { Message } from "@/interfaces/message";

  export default defineComponent({
    name: "HelloWorld",
    props: {
      msg: {
        type: Object as PropType<Message>,
        required: true,
        default: function () {
          return {
            title: "Arrow Function Expression",
            year: 2020,
          };
        },
      },
    },
    setup(props, { emit }) {
      console.log(props);
      const count = ref(0);
      const state: State = reactive({
        title: "",
        year: 2020,
      });
      function pow(x: number, y: number): number {
        return Math.pow(x, y);
      }

      function increment(): void {
        console.log("Emit : Hello World");
        emit("update", "Hello World");
        count.value++;
      }

      return {
        count,
        increment,
        pow,
        state,
      };
    },
  });
</script>
```

The interface `Message` :

```
export interface Message {
    title?: string;
    year?: number;
}
```

The problem what I have is even if I created a `default` for `msg` props didn't work, is not taken into account. I have the message `in the year :`. What I'm doing wrong with default values for props values ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're expecting the default prop's properties to be merged with the passed prop.  That won't work and would mean the prop was modified, and props should not be modified.  The `default` prop is used only when *no* prop has been passed (so you don't need the `required` attribute.)

You'll have to decide between splitting up the object into individual props:

```js
props: {
  title: ...,
  year: ...
}
```

Or use a computed to merge:

```js
setup(props) {
  const msgDefault = {
    title: "Arrow Function Expression",
    year: 2020,
  };
  const merged = computed(() => {
    return Object.assign({}, msgDefault, props.msg);  // shallow merge
  })
  return { merged }
}
```